# Packaging React js web application to .apk

Tags: android, cordova, reactjs, phonegap-build

I have created an basic web application using react js. I would like to transform the application to apk file. I used phonegap to convert my previous html,css,js applications to apk. But i am not sure how to package my react application to apk.I am not sure how to build application in build.phonegap.com

I reffered below link:
http://notes.webutvikling.org/porting-a-react-app-to-phonegap/

But did not get required help. Could anyone please help me by showing path

Comment: If you know how to use phonegap to create an apk from HTML, CSS & JS. you can `npm run build` your react project, get html, css, js and use this to convert your project into .apk

Comment: Yes possibly React Native, Cordova or webview of native android app. Things changed a lot now. Thanks for your comment @SahithVibudhi